# how to pass input tag value to a (click) function and use in service angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular8

This is my component.html, Here I want to get value from numberQuantity input field and pass it to (click) function and use in service function "removeProduct".

```
<input #numberQuantity type="string" name="quant" id="numberQuantity" >

                <button (click)="removeProduct(user, numberQuantity.value)">Remove quantity</button>
```

This is my part of cart.service code

```
async removeProduct(productData, value){
var removeItem;
 console.log(value);
 removeItem = productData['quantity'];
 removeItem = removeItem -value;
```

Comment: What are you trying should work. What's the issue with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using ngModel to the text field, where we can access the value directly in component ts file with out sending from html.

.html

**In html, you mentioned input type="string", change it to input type="text"**

```
<input #numberQuantity type="text" name="quant" id="numberQuantity" [(ngModel)]="quantityValue" >
<button (click)="removeProduct(user)">Remove quantity</button>
```

.ts

```
quantityValue: string;

removeProduct(user) {
   console.log(this.quantityValue); // we can access quantityValue here since it is declared as ngModel in html
   ...
   ...
   // We can call a method in service from here by sending this.quantityValue to service method.
}
```